# Add a graph plot to another one in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, axes

How can make a sum of two plot from matplotlib axes class? 
For example I have an idea like this:

```
>> fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
>> ax1.plot(x1, y1)
>> fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()
>> ax2.plot(x2, y2)
```

I want to have something like:

```
>> ax = ax1 + ax2
```

Someone have an idea or suggest, how to deal with it?
Regards!

Comment: It depends on your definition of "summing two plots". What's your desired output, a plot on top of the other? the two plots side-by-side? Please, try to be a little more specific.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel for your answer, I want to have two curves (ax1, ax2) in ax. In other word I want to have ax being an equivalant of plt.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2)

Comment: >> import numpy as np
   >> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt>> t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

        >> fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(t, t, 'r--')
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(t, t**2, 'bs')
plt.plot(t, t, 'r--', t, t**2, 'bs')